# Outputting R script to Html, but, a preceding chunk assigns a random variable order that needs to be adjusted in a subsequent chunk

Tags: r, knitr

1st chunk outputs 3 identities in a random order, the following block needs to be adjusted to match that random generated order e.g.

```
colnames(random_generated_identity_order)<-c('nameID1','nameID3','nameID2')
```

my subsequent correlation plots depend on properly assigning each identity its proper name so that I can compare it to the true identity I am modeling

```
plot(random_generated_identity_order$nameID1,
 true_ID[,"nameID1"]
```

knitR to html just reruns the code I have supplied leading to a new random order that impacts my plotting later on. How can I output the results of the random order generator and assign the identity order and then directly output to html without it rerunning the code?

Comment: Could you provide a little more code especially for what you are trying to do after? If you don't need it to be totally random you could seed the random number generator (for reproducibility) or if you sort the columns that would maybe fix it?

Comment: Its deconvolution analysis, the random generating stage identifies the same three groups (based on clustering) but in a different  order. So I have no control on which order they are produced. I need to assign each cluster an ID based on my existing knowledge of what each cluster is made up of and the order it is produced. I am attempting caching my data to remove the need to rerun the code but that proving to be less intuitive with knitR's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved caching the random chunk so that it would only be ran during the first knit. After running the initial knit I used the output to assign the identities in the second chunk. After reassigning those identities the knit function is performed a second time and this produced the desired correlation plots.

````
1st chunk
    ```{r setup, include=F, ref.label=c('cachedChunk','adjustedchunk')}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

2nd chunk:cached chunk with randomized function
```{r, cachedChunk, cache=TRUE}


3rd chunk to be adjusted after first knit
```{r, adjustedchunk}
````